# JMeter Embedded Resource Download property

Tags: jmeter

Is it possible to set a global property to automatically retrieve all embedded resources from html files in JMeter. I know we can check/uncheck this in a Http Request in a plan, and in Http Request Defaults, but is there a similar option in a .properties file.

Also, if I do check the option on a Http Request Defaults element, how do I disable it for a individual Http Request in the plan?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not yet possible as of 2.8, there is an enhancement request for this:

- https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=43380

Regarding the second question, the answer is here:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults

See note:

```
   Note: radio buttons only have two states - on or off. This makes it impossible to
   override settings consistently - does off mean off, or does it mean use the current 
   default? JMeter uses the latter (otherwise defaults would not work at all). So if    
   the button is off, then a later element can set it on, but if the button is on, a 
   later element cannot set it off.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `BSF PreProcessor` to the `HTTP Sampler`  that override the default configuration, by setting as, as javascript language, the script code:

```
 sampler.setProperty("HTTPSampler.image_parser",${LOAD_ALL_PAGE_RESOURCES},false);
```

Where `LOAD_ALL_PAGE_RESOURCES` is a User Defined Variables

If you set this `BSF PreProcessor` into a `Thread Group` it is valid for all the `Http Sampler` defined in it.

As described at this link:
http://www.havecomputerwillcode.com/blog/?p=543

Comment: Please don't just link to the answer, as that page may not exist in the future. Please explain in the answer

Comment: In addition to what Ruskin said, the OP already knows this "I know we can check/uncheck this in a Http Request in a plan, and in Http Request Defaults, but is there a similar option in a .properties file."